# Splitting a list into uneven tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I'm trying to split a list of strings into a list of tuples of uneven length containing these strings, with each tuple containing strings initially separated with blank strings. Basically I'd need the parameterized split that I could apply to lists. If my initial list looks like:

```
init = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', 'd e', 'fgh', '', 'ij', '', '', 'k', 'l', '']
```

The last element of this list is always a closing `''`. There can be consecutive `''`s which shall be considered as singles.
The result I need is:

```
end = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd e', 'fgh'), ('ij',), ('k', 'l')]
```

I already have ugly code that does the job and gets out of range once the list is fully popped out:

```
end = []
while init[-1] == u'':
 init.pop()
 l = []
 while init[-1] != u'':
  l.append(init.pop())
 end.append(tuple(l))
```

I'd like to use comprehensions, but having unsuccessfully tried unpacking argument lists, reversing self-referenced lists, using `deque` queues, and various code smells, I'm now doubting whether it makes sense looking for a (nested) comprehension solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` function to group the elements based on their sizes, like this

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> init = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', 'd e', 'fgh', '', 'ij', '', '', 'k', 'l', '']
>>> [tuple(g) for valid, g in groupby(init, key=lambda x: len(x) != 0) if valid]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd e', 'fgh'), ('ij',), ('k', 'l')]
```

This basically groups the elements based on their lengths. If the length of the item is not equal to zero, they will be put in a group, till an element from another group is met. The `key` function would return `True` for the group of elements whose length is not equal to zero, `False` otherwise. We ignore the group with `False` (hence the check `if valid`).

Comment: Is it any nice to replace the lambda function with `bool` to cast the string and get a similar result?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more concise and general approach with `groupby` if you want to split your list with a special delimiter:

```
>>> delimiter = ''
>>> [tuple(g) for k, g in groupby(init, delimiter.__eq__) if not k]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd e', 'fgh'), ('ij',), ('k', 'l')]
```